# The difference between はじめに and はじめて and はじめは

Tags: grammar, translation, phrases

I am trying to figure out the difference between those three sentences.

> はじめにコンピューターを使った。

~ Initially, I used a computer.

> はじめはコンピューターを使った。

~ In the beginning I used a computer. (e.g. but now I use something else)

> はじめてコンピューターを使った。

~ First time I used a computer.

Is there a clear difference in meaning between the first and the second sentence here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> はじめにコンピューターを使った。

Your translations seem correct to me, except I'd translate it "I used a computer first." for more clearness.

To use or not to use は is a deep question, partially because it is seldom reflected in form in European languages. Anyway the usage of は is usually not relevant to the sentence that contains itself, but other sentences around it. In this case, when you just want to say it as a part of "Firstly..., secondly..., finally..." you don't use it, but you should when "At first..., but / on the other hand...".

What can be surely said is that if you start with はじめは, it implies that it becomes no more in some point.

> はじめに言葉があった。 *In the beginning was the word.*

doesn't mean the word disappeared when the God did something, but

> はじめは言葉があった。

does.